# Is there a way to contact person who commented on my topic

Tags: support

I have a question about my Super User post: [How to create inbound rule which only accept Local Lan in win7 firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/1360789/how-to-create-inbound-rule-which-only-accept-local-lan-in-win7-firewall)

One guy has commented on my topic to want me to clarify something, and I checked what he asked and gave my detail information,but when I tried to recomment and even @ this guy, maybe he just forgot my topic, no reply anymore, I was eager to get answer for this topic, so Is there a way to contact the person who commented my topic and get answer from him if he can give answer to my topic?

Comment: No, other than pinging them with the @ like you did, there is no other way to send users direct messages on the SE network.

Comment: Related: [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Comment: As an aside, it would help if you [edited](https://superuser.com/posts/1360789/edit) your original post to include screenshots of the same two tabs grawity was asking you about. This will also have the added benefit of bumping your question back to the front page for more eyes to see it.

Comment: thanks for reply and help. Maybe I should do some editing to my topic, but since my OS language is not english, so maybe screenshots are not very suitable, Anyway, thanks for so many suggestions!

Comment: My last suggestion would be that if this is an important enough problem for you, it might be worth changing your system language settings to English just long enough for you to grab three screenshots: each of the two tabs grawity asked you about, and one of the error message you're getting. There might be something lost in the translation of the error message you posted so it would be helpful to see it in English.

Comment: Thanks again, I have taken your suggestions and edited my post, although it takes a long time to install and setup!

Answer (score 3):

If user doesn't choose to disclose contact details in his or her profile, there's no built-in way in the Stack Exchange platform to contact them other than using an @ comment on that post.